# protractor will not send ENTER key

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I ran into the error "Cannot focus element" when using protractor and tried several solutions offered by the Protractor docs as well as from other questions on S.O. Some of these include:

1)*This ignores the send.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER) line:*

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element)
.click()
.sendKeys("admin")
.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER)
.perform()
```

2) *Gives "cannot focus element" error*

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element)
.click()
.sendKeys("admin")
.perform();

element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

3) Gives "cannot focus element" error

```
element.sendKeys('admin');
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: You don't need all of that. Just use `element.sendKeys("admin");` and then `element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER)`

Comment: That also gives 'cannot focus element' error (updated my question)

Comment: What is the element that you're trying to send keys to?

Comment: It is a popup dialogue box which may have been the problem. I couldn't get the enter key to work so as a workaround I just clicked on the popup text instead.

Comment: For popup's and different windows you should switch to that window. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788106/switching-to-new-window-with-selenium-protractor-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to send the answer key, so as a workaround I just clicked on the suggestion that comes up when entering text