# How to test html links with protractor?

Tags: html, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am new to protractor and would like to test if a link is working.
I understand trying to get the element id but what should i expect that the link equals?

Also has anyone got any good documentation on example protractor tests?
I have been through this `http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial` which was helpful but i need more example of possible tests I could do.

i have this so far:

```
it('should redirect to the correct page', function(){
        element(by.id('signmein').click();
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:8080/web/tfgm_customer/my-account");
    });
```

Comment: The second part of the question is not a really good fit for SO which can lead to the question to be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> would like to test if a link is working

This is a bit broad - it could mean the link to have an appropriate `href`attribute, or that after clicking a link there should be a new page opened.

To check the `href` attribute, use [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
expect(element(by.id('myLink')).getAttribute('href')).toEqual('http://myUrl.com');
```

---

To click the link use [`click()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click), to check the current URL, use [`getCurrentUrl()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl):

```
element(by.id('myLink').click();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://myUrl.com");
```

Note that if there is a non-angular page opened after the click, you need to play around with `ignoreSynchronization` flag, see:

- [Non-angular page opened after a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511013/non-angular-page-opened-after-a-click)

If the link is opened in a new tab, you need to switch to that window, check the URL and then switch back to the main window:

```
element(by.id('myLink')).click().then(function () {
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]).then(function () {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://myUrl.com");
        });

        // switch back to the main window
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: mate, I feel like it's so close, but im not quite there! i have pasted the statement in the code question.

any reason why it doesn't like line 2?

Comment: @BlackMagma missing parenthesis, replace `element(by.id('signmein').click();` with `element(by.id('signmein')).click();`

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense. just one more query, by html code (i didnt write it) looks like this: `<li>
           <a class="signmein" href="/web/tfgm_customer/my-account" rel="nofollow">Sign me in</a>
          </li>`
i.e. there is no id...what can you get it by then?
p.s. thanks, will upvote shortly!

Comment: @BlackMagma at least, two options: `by.css('a.signmein')`, or, `by.linkText('Sign me in')`.

Comment: thanks a lot, mine is still playing up but im sure i'll figure it out.