# Protractor: Is it possible to test that there are no 404 in my app?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm new to protractor, I want to write a test to see that there are no anchors with urls giving 404 errors.

I've seen this [How to test html links with protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212375/how-to-test-html-links-with-protractor), but is for one determined link only, I want to do it for all links in the page.

The test should pass for the http status 200, as stated here [How to use protractor to get the response status code and response text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137881/how-to-use-protractor-to-get-the-response-status-code-and-response-text)

I have two questions:

- Does this test makes sense in protractor?
- Is it possible to test this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its definitely doable and would make sense to do it if the scope is limited since this is not a typical UI test that selenium-webdriver is used for. You could do something like, find all links, get underneath url and fire a GET request using a module like [request](https://github.com/request/request). Here is a pseudo code.

```
var request = require('request');
var assert = require('assert');
element.all(by.tagName('a')).then(function(link) {
   var url = link.getAttribute('href');
   if(url) {
       request(url, function (error, response, body) {
           assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200, 'Status code is not OK');
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: I get the error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
          at Request._callback

Comment: that suggests to me that you got an `error`. Can you print the error?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to implement this as a page object so I could use a simple one line expect statement for each pages spec file. In afterthought I think this could have been achieved in a much simpler manner using an API testing framework such as [cheerio.js](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) but here is how to implement it using protractor and jasmine (using ES2015 syntax so [update node](https://nodejs.org/en/) to the current version) ! Please remember to install the request, bluebird and request-promise npm packages.

**PageObject.js**

```
crawlLinks(){

    const request = require('request');
    const Promise = require('bluebird');
    const rp = require('request-promise');

    return $$('a').then(function(elems){
      return Promise.map(elems, elem => {
        return elem.getAttribute("href").then(function(url){
          if(url){
            var options = {
              method: 'GET',
              uri: url,
              resolveWithFullResponse: true
            };
            return rp(options).then(function(response){
              console.log('The response code for ' + url + ' is ' + response.statusCode);
              return response.statusCode === 200;
            });
          }
        });
      }).then((allCodes) => {
        console.log(allCodes);
        return Promise.resolve(allCodes);
      });
    });
  }
```

**Test**

```
it("should not have broken links", function(){
     expect(pageObject.crawlLinks()).not.toContain(false);
});
```

Comment: It would seem to me the use of `Promise` or `bluebird` is dated. Isn't this addressed directly in Protractor 5.x?

Comment: I answered it before Protractor 5.x was released so yes very dated.

Answer (score 1):

404 errors appear in the browser console (at least in chrome they do) and you can access that from protractor

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLogs) {
   browserLogs.forEach(function(log){
      expect(log).toBeFalsy();
   });
});
```

The code above will cause all console messages to be considered a test failure, you may adapt it to your needs. You can put similar code in `afterAll` on all your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a java demo which may meets your requirement. Also I am not familiar with protractor but hope this can help

```
package com.selenium.webdriver.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Traverse {

   private WebDriver driver;
   private String baseUrl;
   private Map<String, String> tMap;

public Traverse(String url) {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    baseUrl = url;
    tMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
}


//get status code.
public int getRespStatusCodeByGet(String url) throws HttpException, IOException {
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.executeMethod(method);

    return method.getStatusCode();
}

//single page traversal
public boolean search(String url) throws HttpException, IOException {
    if(getRespStatusCodeByGet(url) != 200) {
        System.out.println("Bad page " + url);
        return false;
    }
    driver.get(url);

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for(int i=0;  i<elements.size(); i++) {
        String cUrl = elements.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        String cText = elements.get(i).getText();

        if(cUrl != null && cUrl.startsWith("http") && !tMap.containsKey(cText)) {

            tMap.put(cText, cUrl);

            System.out.println(cUrl);

            search(cUrl);


        }

    }
    return true;
}

//client
public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException {
    Traverse t = new Traverse("http://www.oktest.me/");
    t.search(t.baseUrl);
}
}
```

Check the bad page you can get what you want.

Comment: The question is javascript/protractor specific.