# Testing broken links with Protractor

Tags: web-crawler, http-status-code-404, protractor, angularjs-e2e, broken-links

I'm using Protractor for e2e tests. 
I want to test all the links in my website to see whether they are broken or not.
the thing is that I can't use existing tools for 2 reasons:
1. we are using Angular, so the server doesn't really returns '404' code, but the result is 'http://www../404'
2. there is a login in order to go over the pages, and regular tools don't support it.

Can anyone help with how to do it using Protractor?
Thanks.

Comment: So what is your problem? If you need a kickstart with protractor, there are docs out there: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/

Comment: Thanks! great answer.

Comment: now seriously - I already know Protractor, that was not the question. the question is how to build a spider-crawler link test for my website - to go over all pages and links and check the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor: Is it possible to test that there are no 404 in my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204623/protractor-is-it-possible-to-test-that-there-are-no-404-in-my-app)